# Regex with exclusions on string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression in python with re, but it doesn't work properly.

Im testing with this

```
re.match("111.126.1(2.(12[^1]|13[^5])|(3.(1([.^78]))))", "111.126.13.178")
```

I want to exclude `111.126.12.121`,   `111.126.12.135`  and all the `111.125.13.1[78]X`

Any advice?

Comment: There is a spurious dot in `[.^78]`.

Comment: To match digits other than `5`, use `[0-46-9]`. And so on. `[^5]` matches `;`, `%`, any char other than `5`. Note that `re.match` only anchors the search at the start  of the string. Use `$` at the end of the pattern to anchor it at the end, too. Not sure what you want in the end, try `^111\.126\.1(2\.(12[02-9]\d?|13[0-46-9]\d?)|(3\.(1([0-69])\d?)))$`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, was the point, now works as i want!

Answer (score 0):

First Delete the dot in  [.^78]

And your regular expression can't match '111.126.14.XXX' or '111.127.XX.XXX' and so on .

```
>>> a=re.match("111.126.1(2.(12[^1]|13[^5])|(3.(1([^78]))))", "111.126.14.178")
>>> a
>>>
```

you can use :

```
>>> a=re.match("111.126.1(2.(12[^1]|13[^5])|(3.(1([^78])))|([^23].*))", "111.126.14.178")
>>> a
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10748abe8>
>>> a.group(0)
'111.126.14.178'
>>>
```

and for normal i suggest you add '\' before '.' because '.' is a special character that matches any character except a newline.